# Server dies unexpectedly

Tags: linux, hp-proliant, power-supply-unit

I have a HP Proliant DL380 G8 server that for the past couple of weeks, just suddenly dies. It's happened twice today. The lights on the HDD are just lit instead of blinking, and there is no response from the server. One of the LED is red every time the server dies, but I'm not sure what the LED represents. The LED is circled in the picture below. I have connected both power supply units.

[image]

Is there any log I can check to find out what is going on with the server right before it dies? I'm using RHEL 6.1.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be very surprised indeed if this wasn't a serious hardware issue - you need HPE to help you, log a case and work with them to replace the faulty parts. At this stage it could be a number of parts by the way, these are complex systems and it's easy to jump to conclusions but just work with them and they'll get it sorted for you.

Answer (score 1):

The light is called the "Internal Health LED".

There are instructions and details about the server on the *lid* or top access panel of the system chassis.

[image]

There is also a comprehensive [system maintenance manual](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03254241.pdf) available.

The server can also TELL you what's wrong with it. If you watch the machine boot, errors will be presented at [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test).

In addition, the IML log is accessible from within the OS using `hplog -v`. If that command is not available, it means you're missing the HP tools and health drivers.

On top of that, you can also view the **ILO** interface and check the IML log to see the details of the system health.

This should not be hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: I can't run the hplog command. What do I have to install to be able to use the command? Do they come with the CDs that come with the server?